# Muxing with libav

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, raspberry-pi, mpeg-4, libav

I have a program which is supposed to demux input mpeg-ts, transcode the mpeg2 into h264 and then mux the audio alongside the transcoded video. When I open the resulting muxed file with VLC I neither get audio nor video. Here is the relevant code.

My main worker loop is as follows:

```
void
*writer_thread(void *thread_ctx) {

    struct transcoder_ctx_t *ctx = (struct transcoder_ctx_t *) thread_ctx;
    AVStream *video_stream = NULL, *audio_stream = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *output_context = init_output_context(ctx, &video_stream, &audio_stream);
    struct mux_state_t mux_state = {0};

    //from omxtx
    mux_state.pts_offset = av_rescale_q(ctx->input_context->start_time, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, output_context->streams[ctx->video_stream_index]->time_base);

    //write stream header if any
    avformat_write_header(output_context, NULL);

    //do not start doing anything until we get an encoded packet
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->pipeline.video_encode.is_running_mutex);
    while (!ctx->pipeline.video_encode.is_running) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&ctx->pipeline.video_encode.is_running_cv, &ctx->pipeline.video_encode.is_running_mutex);
    }

    while (!ctx->pipeline.video_encode.eos || !ctx->processed_audio_queue->queue_finished) {
        //FIXME a memory barrier is required here so that we don't race 
        //on above variables 

        //fill a buffer with video data 
        OERR(OMX_FillThisBuffer(ctx->pipeline.video_encode.h, omx_get_next_output_buffer(&ctx->pipeline.video_encode)));

        write_audio_frame(output_context, audio_stream, ctx); //write full audio frame 
        //FIXME no guarantee that we have a full frame per packet?
        write_video_frame(output_context, video_stream, ctx, &mux_state); //write full video frame
        //encoded_video_queue is being filled by the previous command

    }

    av_write_trailer(output_context);

    //free all the resources
    avcodec_close(video_stream->codec);
    avcodec_close(audio_stream->codec);
    /* Free the streams. */
    for (int i = 0; i < output_context->nb_streams; i++) {
        av_freep(&output_context->streams[i]->codec);
        av_freep(&output_context->streams[i]);
    }

    if (!(output_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        /* Close the output file. */
        avio_close(output_context->pb);
    }


    /* free the stream */
    av_free(output_context);
    free(mux_state.pps);
    free(mux_state.sps);
}
```

The code for initialising libav output context is this:

```
static 
AVFormatContext *
init_output_context(const struct transcoder_ctx_t *ctx, AVStream **video_stream, AVStream **audio_stream) {
    AVFormatContext *oc;
    AVOutputFormat *fmt;
    AVStream *input_stream, *output_stream;
    AVCodec *c;
    AVCodecContext *cc;
    int audio_copied = 0; //copy just 1 stream

    fmt = av_guess_format("mpegts", NULL, NULL);
    if (!fmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] Error guessing format, dying\n");
        exit(199);
    }

    oc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!oc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] Error allocating context, dying\n");
        exit(200);
    }

    oc->oformat = fmt;
    snprintf(oc->filename, sizeof(oc->filename), "%s", ctx->output_filename);
    oc->debug = 1;
    oc->start_time_realtime = ctx->input_context->start_time;
    oc->start_time = ctx->input_context->start_time;
    oc->duration = 0;
    oc->bit_rate = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ctx->input_context->nb_streams; i++) {
        input_stream = ctx->input_context->streams[i];
        output_stream = NULL;
        if (input_stream->index == ctx->video_stream_index) {
            //copy stuff from input video index
            c = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H264);
            output_stream = avformat_new_stream(oc, c);
            *video_stream = output_stream;
            cc = output_stream->codec;
            cc->width = input_stream->codec->width;
            cc->height = input_stream->codec->height;
            cc->codec_id = CODEC_ID_H264;
            cc->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
            cc->bit_rate = ENCODED_BITRATE;
            cc->time_base = input_stream->codec->time_base;

            output_stream->avg_frame_rate = input_stream->avg_frame_rate;
            output_stream->r_frame_rate = input_stream->r_frame_rate;
            output_stream->start_time = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

        } else if ((input_stream->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) && !audio_copied)  { 
            /* i care only about audio */
            c = avcodec_find_encoder(input_stream->codec->codec_id);
            output_stream = avformat_new_stream(oc, c);
            *audio_stream = output_stream;
            avcodec_copy_context(output_stream->codec, input_stream->codec);
            /* Apparently fixes a crash on .mkvs with attachments: */
            av_dict_copy(&output_stream->metadata, input_stream->metadata, 0);
            /* Reset the codec tag so as not to cause problems with output format */
            output_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
            audio_copied = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oc->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            oc->streams[i]->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        if (oc->streams[i]->codec->sample_rate == 0)
            oc->streams[i]->codec->sample_rate = 48000; /* ish */
    }

    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] AVFMT_NOFILE set, allocating output container\n");
        if (avio_open(&oc->pb, ctx->output_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] error creating the output context\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return oc;
}
```

Finally this is the code for writing audio:

```
static
void
write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st, struct transcoder_ctx_t *ctx) {
    AVPacket pkt = {0}; // data and size must be 0;
    struct packet_t *source_audio;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    if (!(source_audio = packet_queue_get_next_item_asynch(ctx->processed_audio_queue))) {
        return;
    }

    pkt.stream_index = st->index;
    pkt.size = source_audio->data_length;
    pkt.data = source_audio->data;
    pkt.pts = source_audio->PTS;
    pkt.dts = source_audio->DTS;
    pkt.duration = source_audio->duration;
    pkt.destruct = avpacket_destruct;
    /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
    if (av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] Error while writing audio frame\n");
    }

    packet_queue_free_packet(source_audio, 0);
}
```

A resulting mpeg4 file can be obtained from here: `http://87.120.131.41/dl/mpeg4.h264`

I have ommited the write_video_frame code since it is a lot more complicated and I might be making something wrong there as I'm doing timebase conversation etc. For audio however I'm doing 1:1 copy. Each packet_t packet contains data from av_read_frame from the input mpegts container. In the worst case I'd expect that my audio is working and not my video. However I cannot get either of those to work. Seems the documentation is rather vague on making things like that - I've tried both libav and ffmpeg irc channels to no avail. Any information regarding how I can debug the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you use mpegts for output format. I don't think it's correct, try a container like mp4 or avi

Comment: avi did not help, however with mp4 I did get picture but no sound. What I cannot understand is why it would matter what the container is?

Comment: I would need to see more of the program. I can extract the audio (Its a clip from Dirty Jobs) But something is terribly wrong with the video stream.

Answer (score 2):

When different containers yield different results in libav it is almost always a timebase issue. All containers have a time_base that they like, and some will accept custom values... sometimes.

You must rescale the time base before putting it in the container. Generally tinkering with the mux state struct isn't something you want to do and I think what you did there doesn't do what you think. Try printing out all of the timebases to find out what they are.

Each frame you must recalculate PTS at least. If you do it before you call encode the encoder will produce the proper DTS. Do the same for the audio, but generally set the DTS it to AV_NO_PTS and sometimes you can get away with setting the audio PTS to that as well. To rescale easily use the av_rescale(...) functions.

Be careful assuming that you have MPEG-2 data in a MPEG-TS container, that is not always true.